# Adding points to Highcharts 3D scatter chart after the chart has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to automatically add data points to a 3D scatter chart using ajax.
The problem is, I can't seem to get the chart to accept my y-axis data point I get from the ajax script. The x and z values it accepts just fine, but not the y-value. But if I input the y-value as a plain number, it works just fine.. There's some simple little thing that's wrong, but I just can't figure it out...

Here's a modified version of the Highcharts 3D demo to illustrate what I'm on about: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea871qhn/1/)

Here's the relevant code:

```
var result = "5,3,8"
var res = result.split(",");

var xval = res[0];
var yval = res[1];
var zval = res[2];

function works() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts()
    chart.series[0].addPoint([xval, 6, zval]);
}

function doesntwork() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts()
    chart.series[0].addPoint([xval, yval, zval]);
}
```

Normally I would get the result variable from the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse values to float.

```
var xval = parseFloat(res[0]);
var yval = parseFloat(res[1]);
var zval = parseFloat(res[2]);
```